# How to make a library in c++ like stl

Tags: c++, linker, object-files

I have made my own implementations of many of the STL features like Vectors, Lists, BST, Queue, Stack and given them all the functions that an STL corresponding library has....

Now i want to use this library by

```
#include "myLibName.h"
```

What I Did :

```
g++ -o -c myLib myLib.cpp
```

From This I got the object file...

But when i compile programs i have to link the object file myself...

Is there any way that i can do without linking...like the `iostream` and the other libraries are linked automatically.

I know that a **SHARED OBJECT file (eg. libc.so in C)** is where all the implementations are held in C....
If that's the solution then how do i make any and **use it like other standard libraries in C++ without linking object file every time.**

PS: After a lot of efforts i have created these libraries myself...Now Struck at the final step...Pls Help...

Comment: It pretty much depends on whether all your stuff is templates. If it is, then all you need is put it into the headers.

Comment: All Implementations are for templates.....Also i have created the header files for them also...i m struck as in how to tell the compiler that the implementations are in the file myLib.o without linking each time....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make your build process cleaner for large projects in which you need to link multiple projects, you can use Makefiles.
After that you need to just type `make` at the terminal to compile and build the whole project.

Another solution is the following, although many people don't recommend it,

```
      header.h
     class Foo
     { 
         // some variable and method declarations. 
     }
```

header.h is your header file which will contain your declarations.

```
    implement.cpp // this is the implementation file
    #include "header.h" 
    // Now implement various methods you declared in your "header.h" file.
```

implement.cpp is your implementation file which contains the implementation and the definition of static members.

```
    main.cpp
    #include "header.cpp" 
    // use your methods.
```

Now you don't need to link your object files, just do `g++ -Wall main.cpp`

Answer (score 4):

You can't unless you're going to write your own toolchain. GCC links in its runtime and standard library because it's GCC and knows that it should; it won't magically do the same with *your* library.

Conventionally, either make your library header-only or ship a `.a`/`.so`/`.dll` for devs to link against at linktime. In the latter two cases you'll also need to ship the `.so`/`.dll` for *users* to link against at runtime.

Comment: You can see what goes wrong when you do not link to the standard libraries if you link C++ using gcc (as opposed to g++). You end up with loads of missing symbols.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should probably [differentiate between STL and the `Standard C++ Library`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12750531/stl-does-every-compiler-implement-it-differently).

Each compiler comes with its own implementation of the Standard Library, some of them being (at least mostly) compatible (see clang++ and g++). So basically your way to go would be to modify the compiler you are using.

If you are writing [header-only implementations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Header-only), then no library is needed to be built and you can use it without linking. But in that case your work has to be distributed as source and not as library + header.

If you want to simply distribute your library and do not mind to link against the shared or static library you distributed, you should build a shared or static library, depending on the case. But you will have to link it when it is used.

Comment: modifying the compiler would be rather difficult task and i am not the most qualified person to do so....doesn't C++ provide a way so that we also can make our own libraries....?

Comment: You can, but you got to link them. Or you build and provide your own implementation of whatever library your compiler is pulling and replace it on the system.

Comment: then how do programmers provide their libraries for use to other people.....?? There has to be some way for sure....

Comment: If I provide a library (.so/.a) in my project, people using it have to link against. Same goes for boost, ZeroMQ and Google Potobuf. Unless the library is header-only, like Boost Asio.

Comment: If i make a header only library, and then i wish to distribute my library to others then they will be able to see the code i have written right....? I don't want such a thing....i only want to give them the implementations...

Comment: @PRP non instantiated templates are pretty much the same thing as source code.